# How to delete the data in two rows in different table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

How to delete the data in a row in table 1 whose primary key is using as a foreign key in 2nd table.. I am facing the problem here

```
delete from ASSIGNMENT 
where proj_num=18
delete from PROJECT 
where proj_num=18
```

`proj_num` is the primary key in `project` and foreign key in assignment.

How to do this task in one `delete` query ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create/edit the relationship between the two tables in order to set the delete behaviour to `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then you can just delete the proj_num=18 from the PROJECT table, and it will automatically delete the related records from the ASSIGNMENT table. Hope it works for you.

```
ALTER TABLE ASSIGNMENT
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_proj
    FOREIGN KEY (proj_num)
    REFERENCES PROJECT (proj_num)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't have access to the table design you may use this.

```
DELETE proj
FROM Project AS proj INNER JOIN Assignment AS assn
ON proj.proj_num = asn.proj_num
WHERE proj_num = 18
```